# How to replace the href value using cheerio in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I am trying to replace the href value from html content but not working.How to use cheerio for that and find the solution.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>
<div>
<a href="#" id="reset" class="reset">Link</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```
var cheerio = require("cheerio");
var fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('./public/index.html', { encoding: 'utf-8' }, function(err, html) 
{
  if (err) {
      console.log(err);
  } else {
      const $ = cheerio.load(html); 
      $("a").each(function() {
          var id = $(this).attr("id");
          var url = "http://www.google.com";
          var new_href = encodeURIComponent(url);
          if (id == "reset") {
             $(this).attr("href", new_href);
          } 
      });
    }
});
```

Comment: How are you verifying it's not working? The term *"not working"* is virtually meaningless without any debugging details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey @Pappa S As i have check in your code `a` tag value is replace.

```
var cheerio = require("cheerio");
var fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('./public/index.html', { encoding: 'utf-8' }, function(err, html) {
  console.log(html)
if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
         const $ = cheerio.load(html); 
         $("a").each(function() {
          var id = $(this).attr("id");
          var url = "http://www.google.com";
          // var new_href = encodeURIComponent(url);
            if (id == "reset") {
               $(this).attr("href", url);
          }
          console.log($.html());
     });
  }
});
```

// output

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>
<div>
<a href="http://www.google.com" id="reset" class="reset">Link</a>
</div>


</body></html>
```

As i have seen html code in console value is replaced. But You need to write that Also in html file also. hope that will help.